# Faster Python screensharing with websockets

Tags: python, image, networking, websocket, screenshot

My python screenshare program with websockets is very slow and looks like it only gets 1 or 2 frames per second

client side using mss to take screenshot

```
sct = mss.mss()
moniter = sct.monitors[1]
sct.compression_level = 7
im = sct.grab(moniter)
raw_bytes = mss.tools.to_png(im.rgb, im.size)
return base64.encodebytes(raw_bytes) # the bytes are directly sent through the websocket
```

server side receiving image

```
img_bytes = base64.decodebytes(await self.ws.recv()) # receive bytes and decode base64
img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(img_bytes))
```

How can I make this screensharing faster?
Thanks

Comment: You're sending only what video folks call [intra frames](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intra-frame_coding)...